# Role system not working properly

Tags: bukkit

So I created a command to get the players current "role" or the arraylist the player is in, but I have an issue where both  messages gets sent to the player telling the player that he is, and is not in a role. Why is this happening?

COMMAND CLASS:

```
public class RoleCommand implements CommandExecutor{

private Main main;

public RoleCommand(Main main) {
    this.main = main;

}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Role")) {
        if(Roles.innocent.contains(p.getName())) {
            p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYour current game-role is: §a§lINNOCENT");
        } else {
            p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYou have not been assigned any role!");

        } 

        if(Roles.traitor.contains(p.getName())) {
            p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYour current game-role is: §c§lTRAITOR");
        } else {
            p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYou have not been assigned any role!");
        }

    }
    return true;
    }  
 }
```

ARRAYLIST CLASS:

```
public class Roles implements Listener{

private Main main;

public Roles(Main main) {
    this.main = main;

}

public static ArrayList<String> innocent = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> traitor = new ArrayList<String>();
//private static List<String> detective = new ArrayList<String>();
 }
```

And btw the player gets assigned an role when he joins the server.

Comment: Also, please avoid using cmd.getName().equals(etc). This will break any other aliases.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue, you must evaluate correctly the conditions on your RoleCommand class.
Take a look:

Instead of your current onCommand, use:

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

Player p = (Player) sender;
if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Role")) {
    if(Roles.innocent.contains(p.getName())) {
          p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYour current game-role is: §a§lINNOCENT");
    } else if (Roles.traitor.contains(p.getName()) {
          p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYour current game-role is: §c§lTRAITOR");
    } else  {
          p.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§cYou have not been assigned any role!");
    }


}
return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted, because this answer is correct.

Comment: @RoccoDev It happens :P

Answer (score 0):

Because it's evaluating both the `Roles.innocent` and `Roles.traitor` expressions before returning. For each expression it evaluates, you're going to send one response. You need to break out or return after sending the correct message.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having is because you're code still continues on after it has found what role the player is in.
Another thing that would break your code is if the sender is not an instance of Player - for example if the command is executed from the console. Also, this method always returns true which would stop other commands being executed. Try changing your onCommand method to the following:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String lbl, String[] args){
    if(lbl.equalsIgnoreCase("role")){
        if(sender instanceof Player){
            String name = ((Player) sender).getName();
            if(Roles.innocent.contains(name)){
                sender.sendMessage("Current role: Innocent");
            }else if(Roles.traitor.contains(name)){
                sender.sendMessage("Current role: Traitor");
            }else{
                sender.sendMessage("You don't have a role yet");
            }
        }else{
            sender.sendMessage("only players can execute this command");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: You'll want to change the message that get sent.